# AngularJs default language AngularTranslation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I want to set default language by user country, but i cannot set preferredLanguage in $.get. I am using "http://ipinfo.io". Is there any other way to set default language?

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(function config($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    $translateProvider
        .translations('en', {
            TRANLATION : 'Translation',
            BUTTON_LANG_EN : 'English',
            BUTTON_LANG_SK : 'Slovak',
            HOME: 'Home',
        })
        .translations('sk', {
            TRANLATION : 'Preklad',
            BUTTON_LANG_EN : 'Anglicky',
            BUTTON_LANG_SK : 'Slovensky',
            HOME: 'Zakladne informacie',
        });

    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
        if(response.country == 'SK'){
            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sk');
            }else{
                $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
            }
        }, "jsonp");
});
```

Comment: nope :( condition is Ok,.. when use $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sk'); outside of $.get its work correctly..

Comment: Maybe add this part to run in ng ? Im on phone cannot debug that xd

Comment: this part is in config for translate.. its running on page start. I am able to write language to console in this part of code, but i cannot set preferredLanguage..

Comment: Did you tried using `$http` instead of `$.get`?

Comment: no but data comes from ipinfo.. problem is in this command $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sk');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running in an async issue, so, when the ajax call `$.get` (assuming is jQuery) is resolved you are out from the config phase of angular js...

Try something like that:

```js
in app.js 
var app = angular.module('langTest', ['pascalprecht.translate','calsethTranslate'])
  .config(function($injector, $translateProvider){
    jQuery
    .when({})
            .then(function() {
                return $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function(response) {
                    return response;
                },'jsonp')
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                var lang = response.country === 'SK' ? 'SK' : 'EN';
                var _$injector = angular.element(document.body).injector();
                console.log(lang);
                if (_$injector.has('$translate')) {
                    console.log("has "+lang);
                  return _$injector.get('$translate').use(lang);
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am begginer in this.. you code giving me this: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24translate

Comment: this happens because you are still into a config phase or because the $injector provided can't access to the services instances, so, try as I updated my answer.

Comment: I can see you made it "on fly" I made little edit and works fine... gr8 work thx

Comment: Yep, this should work but you are doing wrong because this means that you're coming outside from the angular environment...

A good solution could be using a resolve in your router which is resolved at top... using jQuery for doing xhr requests in angular is a very bad idea...

Comment: Well, How I said I am begginer.. Do you know any tutorial or some best practisies for this? Now it is working, but you say It is very bad idea and I do not have Idea why.. :) I am sorry for my silly questions.. :(